# Serial port access in vxworks not working

Tags: serial-port, vxworks

I am in a need to send data thru serial port in vxworks. I am using the following code. But
it is not working.can anyone point out what went wrong?

```
int f;

if(f=open("/tyCo/1",O_RDWR,0)<0)
{
    printf("Error opening serial port.");
    return 1;
}

write(f,"hello",5);
```

after running this code, no data is comming thru serial port but instead it comes thru
terminal(Tornado shell). The system has two serial devices /tyCo/1 and /tyCo/0. I tried them both, but the problem persists.

Thanks in adavnce
Likhin.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the baud rate?

```
if (iocl(m_fd, FIOBAUDRATE, rate )) == ERROR )
{
    //throw error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are using the wrong name for the device, and that Tornado Shell is set to your default device. From [vxdev.com](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/guide/c-iosys.html%20vxdev):

> If a matching device name cannot be found, then the I/O function is directed
>   at a default device. You can set this default device to be any device in the
>   system, including no device at all, in which case failure to match a device
>   name returns an error. You can obtain the current default path by using
>   ioDefPathGet( ). You can set the default path by using ioDefPathSet( ).

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd parameter of "open" command is, if I am not wrong, the mode. I do not really understand what it is needed for in vxworks, except for code comparability with UNIX. In short -try to give some value like 0644 or 0666. I think this will help.